# Ninject Dependency Injection Using Reflection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

```
public DefaultRepositoryRegistry(IKernel kernel)
{
    foreach (var tuple in DefaultContractList())
    {
        var iRepo = tuple.Item1;
        var repo = tuple.Item2;
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<Tuple<Type, Type>> DefaultContractList()
{
    var contractList = new List<Tuple<Type, Type>>()
    {
        #region Mongo

        Tuple.Create(typeof (IMongoRepository), typeof (MongoRepository)),

        #endregion Mongo
    };

    return contractList;
}
```

I am unable to do dynamic binding e.g.

```
foreach (var tuple in DefaultContractList())
{
    var iRepo = tuple.Item1;
    var repo = tuple.Item2;

    kernel.Bind<iRepo>().To<repo>();
}
```

Any help as to why Ninject doesn't accept this type of binding?
I am doing this so that one can use the same set of services in for different dependency injection frameworks.

Comment: When you say "doesn't accept", are you getting an exception? Or is there just no binding?

Comment: It doesn't recognize the iRepo and repo as types such that they can be added to the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax probably won't compile:

```
foreach (var tuple in DefaultContractList())
{
    var iRepo = tuple.Item1;
    var repo = tuple.Item2;

    kernel.Bind<iRepo>().To<repo>();
}
```

The bits inside the angle brackets are called *type parameters* (e.g. `<iRepo>` and `<repo>`), and they should be the actual type names, not variables of type `System.Type`. It just so happens, though, that Ninject has an alternate form of binding that will probably work perfectly for you:

```
foreach (var tuple in DefaultContractList())
{
    var iRepo = tuple.Item1;
    var repo = tuple.Item2;

    kernel.Bind(iRepo).To(repo);
}
```

Comment: If this solves your issue, please mark it as the answer =)